# Convert the Stress and Gender field with Yes = 1 and No = 0 for Stress and Male = 1 and Female = 0 for Gender field. Produce a cross table

Tags: r, typeconverter

I have a Df with

```
$ Gender      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...

$ Stress      : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 ...
```

I am trying to convert Stress to

Yes = 1 and No = 0

and Gender to

Male =1 and Female = 0

so i can put the result of this in a Cross table with distribution between gender and stress in percentage

Comment: The question title says "sum" and "multiply", yet the question asks for a cross table. Which is it? Have you looked at `table(.)` and `xtabs(.)` (for the cross-tab portion)?

Comment: Will this be a 2x2 table with percentage of the total, or are you expecting marginal percentages? Are you looking for `prop.table(table(Df))`?

Comment: i would like to find the percentage distribution between Gender
and Stress in 2x2 table